# Find the substring between the first 'a' char in email column before '@'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the substring between the first 'a' char in email column before '@',

i have written the below sql-query ,

but i think i can do it in better way .

```
SELECT 
    email,
    CASE
        WHEN
            LENGTH(SUBSTR(email, 0, POSITION('@' IN email))) - LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR(email, 0, POSITION('@' IN email)),
                        'a',
                        '')) > 1
        THEN
            SUBSTR(email,
                POSITION('a' IN email) + 1,
                POSITION('a' IN SUBSTR(email,
                        POSITION('a' IN email) + 1)) - 1)
        ELSE ''
    END AS deelstring
FROM
    persoon
```

correction for the sql-query

Comment: you almost always want CHAR_LENGTH, not LENGTH, though in this case it makes no difference

Comment: substring_index is often better than substr+position, though it behaves differently when the substring is not found.

Comment: it would be very much clearer if you provided sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You have to test every step of your query epecially, when you want to extract parts.

As ysth Length only can count ascii charakter, which doesn't matter when you check for if there are any `a` in the email, but when extracting you need the length for all characters even non ASCII.

```
CREATE TABLe persoon (email varchar(50))
```

```
INSERT INTO persoon VALUEs('testa11111111@test.com'),('tÚsta11Ú111111@test.com')
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT 
    email,
      CASE
        WHEN
            LENGTH(SUBSTR(email, 1, POSITION('@' IN email)-1)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR(email, 1, POSITION('@' IN email)-1),
                        'a',
                        '')) >= 1
        THEN
             SUBSTR(email,
                POSITION('a' IN email) + 1,
                CHAR_LENGTH (SUBSTR(email, 1, POSITION('@' IN email)-1))
  - POSITION('a' IN email) )
  ELSE ''
    END AS deelstring
FROM
    persoon
```

| email | deelstring |
| --- | --- |
| testa11111111@test.com | 11111111 |
| tÚsta11Ú111111@test.com | 11Ú111111 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Scsdh2T2)

Comment: if the email may contain non-ascii characters, this isl definitely wrong unless you pass CHAR_LENGTH to substr instead of LENGTH

Answer (score 0):

There're at least two ways to extract a substring:

1. Extract the substring from start position to end position, or
2. Remove prefix/suffix before/after start/end position

Piggyback on data prepared by @nbk with the 2nd approach, this may work for you:

```
select email,
       regexp_replace(email,'^.*a','') as remove_prefix,
       regexp_replace(email,'@.*$','') as remove_suffix,
       regexp_replace(regexp_replace(email,'^.*a',''),'@.*$','') as remove_both
  from persoon;
```

Outcome:

```
email                 |remove_prefix    |remove_suffix|remove_both|
----------------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
testa11111111@test.com|11111111@test.com|testa11111111|11111111   |
```